# How to split an array into 3?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with 9 elements and i want to split into 3 with all possibilities.

How can i do that?

for better understanding, choose 3 of 9 then choose 3 of 6 and the rest will be last. and there are 1680 possibilities. I want them.

Comment: Can you give us your context? It might help. And I'm curious.

Comment: For example i have an array like this: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and i want to split like this [1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9] and [1,2,5], [4,3,6], [7,8,9]. I hope you get better.

Comment: I meant could you tell us why you're trying to do that?

Comment: how do you want to split you array? Do you want to spit every 3 consecutive numbers then split?

Comment: Thiago, i want to do it because i want to learn java better.
GRC, it can be consecutive numbers and it can be non consecutive. every possibilities.

Comment: Is result like `[1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9]` considered same as `[7,8,9] [1,2,3] [4,5,6]`?

Comment: Also do you consider arrays like `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,1]` same?

Comment: Pshemo, yes if it's possible

Comment: The best way to learn is try to do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a permutations problem than a Java problem but basically you can just calculate all permutations of { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 } and once you get the permutation take the first 3 as your first array, the second 3 as your second array and the last 3 as your third array. BTW, I chose 0-8 instead of 1-9 because array index starts at 0.

For example, the first permutation is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I split that into three parts/arrays, [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8].

I do not claim that this is the best approach or that this code is optimized but it was a fun puzzle. :)

```
public class Permutations
{
    private boolean[] used;
    private StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    private final String in;
    private String[] originalArray = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" }; // this can be changed to any array, e.g. int[]

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Permutations p = new Permutations("012345678");
        p.permute();
    }

    public Permutations(final String str)
    {
        in = str;
        used = new boolean[in.length()];
    }

    public void permute()
    {
        if (out.length() == in.length())
        {
            System.out.println("Permutation: " + out);
            loadArrays(out);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (used[i])
                continue;
            out.append(in.charAt(i));
            used[i] = true;
            permute();
            used[i] = false;
            out.setLength(out.length() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void loadArrays(StringBuilder p)
    {
        String[] array1 = new String[3];
        String[] array2 = new String[3];
        String[] array3 = new String[3];
        array1[0] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(0, 1))];
        array1[1] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(1, 2))];
        array1[2] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(2, 3))];
        array2[0] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(3, 4))];
        array2[1] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(4, 5))];
        array2[2] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(5, 6))];
        array3[0] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(6, 7))];
        array3[1] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(7, 8))];
        array3[2] = originalArray[Integer.parseInt(p.substring(8, 9))];

        System.out.println(String.format("Array1: [%s,%s,%s]", array1[0], array1[1], array1[2]));
        System.out.println(String.format("Array2: [%s,%s,%s]", array2[0], array2[1], array2[2]));
        System.out.println(String.format("Array3: [%s,%s,%s]", array3[0], array3[1], array3[2]));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

BTW, there are 362880 permutations not 1680. :)

Comment: Well just remember that [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] is the same as [3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7]

Comment: I saw his comment on that but he didn't seem overly concerned with it so I wasn't too worried about it. I'm not sure this is a good problem if your intent is to learn Java... this is more about finding a good math solution, IMHO. :)

Comment: Agreed. My solution is extremely janky, but will totally work. I'd probably do some sort of intersection of permutations to remove duplicates if I spent more time on this

Answer (score 0):

The most naive approach, but probably more efficient that removing permutations of permutations is as follows:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
    for (int b = a + 1; b < 9; b++) {
        for (int c = b + 1; c < 9: c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < 9; d++) {
                //make sure we haven't used these values
                if (d == a || d == b || d == c)
                    continue;
                for (int e = d + 1; e < 9; e++) {
                    if (e == a || e == b || e == c)
                        continue;
                    for (int f = e + 1; f < 9; f++) {
                        if (f == a || f == b || f == c)
                            continue;
                        //group the already used values
                        int used = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
                        //create the first and second triplets
                        String[] first = {originalArray[a], originalArray[b], originalArray[c]};
                        String[] second = {originalArray[d], originalArray[e], originalArray[f]};
                        int g = -1;
                        int h = -1;
                        int i = -1;
                        //find the values that haven't been used
                        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                            boolean found = false;
                            for (int k = 0; k < used.length; k++) {
                                if (j == used[k]) {
                                    found = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!found) {
                                if (g < 0) {
                                    g = j;
                                } else if (h < 0) {
                                    h = j;
                                } else if (i < 0) {
                                    i = j;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //create the third triplet
                        String[] third = {originalArray[g], originalArray[h], originalArray[i]};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```